# How to use a header bar with java-gnome?

Tags: java, linux, user-interface, gtk, gnome

I've started using java-gnome to create GUIs using GTK with Java. Everything is working pretty well so far, yet there's one thing I don't find anyhting about.

I'd like my window to use a [header bar](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkHeaderBar.html), however I can't find a HeaderBar class. Is this working another way? This is my first time using Gtk by the way.

Thank you for everything

Comment: GtkHeaderBar is available since Gtk+ 3.0 so you must be explicit about which version you're using. If Gtk+ 3.0 so you have the GtkWindow method/function `set_titlebar` which allows you to set the header bar to that window. If you don't find the HeaderBar class so probably you're uisng Gtk+ 2.0.

Comment: Well, java-gnome depends on GTK >= 3.0.4, and the Window class does not have such a method or property.. My guess is that the implementation is incomplete, for now.

Comment: Not really sure which minor version was but i guess that since gnome 3 appeared it had headerbars. I did check the java gtk documentation and both, headerbars and set_titlebar method, were not there.

Comment: From the GTK C API, GtkHeaderBars exist since Gtk+ 3.10.

Comment: Filed an issue. https://github.com/afcowie/java-gnome/issues/20